# Shell : Replace character only inside curly braces?

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have large set file files congaing following formatted lines. I need to replace `|` character with blank only inside `{"USER":"AD","DESCRIPTION":"\"<some non english characters>  |\n<some non english characters>","LINK":"sample"}` which contains open and closed curly braces. So for below text

```
|||||samA|sam2||||{"USER":"AD","DESCRIPTION":"\"<some non english characters>  |\n<some non english characters>","LINK":"sample"}||||data|string|
```

output is

```
|||||samA|sam2||||{"USER":"AD","DESCRIPTION":"\"<some non english characters>  \n<some non english characters>","LINK":"sample"}||||data|string|
```

I have been trying various sed formats to do this for several hours still no luck. Is there a way i could do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr:

```
sed  '/{[^}]*|/{:a;s/\({[^}]*\)|\([^}]*}\)/\1 \2/;ta}'
```

short explanation:

`/{[^}]*|/` -- filter only lines with pattern where we will apply the change (actually that part can be removed, but might speed up processing for huge files)

`:a;...;ta` -- a cycle which will iterate through line until replace statement changes nothing. needed in case you have multiple `|` inside curly braces

`s/\({[^}]*\)|\([^}]*}\)/\1 \2/;` will replace `|` inside curly braces. one at a time.