# Fixing the fields in an incorrectly generated file

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have a text file that has not been created properly.  I am trying to get the people who create the text file to fix their output, but that is a long process and in the meantime I want to try repairing what I have, as a temporary workaround.

The file is supposed to contain 9 fields separated by a vertical bar (`|`) delimiter.   Unfortunately, the second field is *also* several fields separated by a vertical bar.  And there's no escaping or quoting being used.  So what I have has a lot more than 9 fields.

I want to repair this, by taking the first field and the last 7 fields as-is, and transforming the fields in the middle into a single field, either suppressing the delimiters or replacing them with spaces.

For examples:

```
field1|field2|field3||||||field9
1a|DAVID|JOY|02022|4|5|6|7|8|9
1b|DAVID|JOY|ZYN|02022|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

I am expecting output as

```
field1|field2|field3||||||field9
1a|DAVIDJOY|02022|4|5|6|7|8|9
1b|DAVIDJOYZYN|2022|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

How can I do this using shell-level tools?

Comment: is it possible to change whatever program is generating the file, so that a different character than | is used as a field separator?

Comment: Do you actually mean _10_ fields, because that's what your expected output contains?

Comment: Tim, that's possible but it takes a long process for the sourcing team to implement new changes. I am working on temporary workarounds through command line before accessing original file

Comment: No both source and target contains 9 fields. I only want to suppress pipe for the column2. Using awk -F "|" 'NF!=10 { print $0;}' I am able to fetch the records which have more than 9 delimiters. I need help here

Comment: Sorry I have removed the extra pipe which I have not noticed.

Comment: You also say field 2 may contain **a** pipe delimiter. Clearly you mean one or more, or possibly zero or more.

Comment: Paul, its dynamic it might contain zero or 1 or more as it is a descriptive field. The rest of fields I don't see any issues.

Comment: "_I need to replace the | with space_" your output doesn't seem to contain a space anywhere

Comment: Answer comments indicate that the question is not asking what the questioner wants.  A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/554740/5132 .

Comment: "_second field data itself contains a pipe delimiter_" in your example, does this mean that the first line's second field datum is actually `field2|field3`? Because if so that is wildly confusing.

Comment: @JdeBP I don't see the relevance of that question here. In your linked question there is some context to identify the character to be replaced. Here there is none.

Comment: Actually, there is. See the answer comment by the questioner that I mentioned.  What xe actually wants is distinctly at variance to the question that xe asked, but is also specific as to how to deal with extra vertical bars.  This question needs to be written properly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because we are being asked to write some code to guess with no context which pipe
 characters are unwanted data and which are field separators.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear. Field three might contain zipcode or null.

Comment: @JaswanthKadiyala Because of the nature of the question itself. It is unclear what you mean by "field 3".  Furthermore, _all_ clarifications should go into the text of the question, not be left in comments.

Answer (score 14):

With GNU `sed`, you could use:

```
sed ':1;s/|/|/9;T;s/|//2;t1'
```

which joins the second with the third field (deletes the second occurrence of `|`) as many times as necessary until there is no more than 9 fields in the output.

On an input like:

```
1|a|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
1|a|b|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
1|a|b|c|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

It gives:

```
1|a|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
1|ab|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
1|abc|3|4|5|6|7|8|9
```

On non-GNU systems, you could use [@RakeshSharma's POSIX `sed` variant](/a/555494) or `perl` instead:

```
perl -F'[|]' -lae 'BEGIN {$" = ""; $, = "|"}
                   print $F[0], "@F[1..$#F-7]", @F[-7..-1]'
```

Comment: Here you go Stephane. Thanks for understanding my question, but imagine if I have values like .1|a|b|c|d|3|4|5|6|7|8|9 or 1|a|b|c|d|e|..3|4|5|6|7|8|9 more dynamic in nature

Comment: @JaswanthKadiyala, then it gives `.1|abcd|3|4|5|6|7|8|9` and `1|abcde|..3|4|5|6|7|8|9`. Is it not what you want?

Comment: Well that's what want it. Great, I have tested with multiple records.

Comment: Stephane sorry Initially I thought it works for the logic which has only two delimiters in field2 but its working dynamically when I pass more than 2 pipe delimiters

Comment: Thank you stephane

Comment: @JaswanthKadiyala If you found the answer useful, please consider accepting it so that others facing a similar problem may find it more easily.

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU awk

```
awk '{ 
   while ( gsub(/\|/, "|") > 8 )
      $0 = gensub(/\|/, "", 2)
}1' file
```

Using Posix sed:

```
sed -e '
    :a
    s/|/&/9;tb
    b
    :b
    s///2;ta
' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an array by parsing the file with delimiters:

```
IFS='|' read -r -a fields thefile
```

Join terms from #2 to #8th before end:

```
field=${fields[1]} ;  
i=2 ; 
max=$((${#fields[*]}-8));  
while [[ $i -le $max ]] ; 
do 
    field="$field ${fields[$i]}" ; 
    (( ++i )) ; 
done  ; 
echo $field
```

Answer (score 0):

You are really looking for the 2nd and 3rd field, so if there is a single line in the file:

```
IFS='|' read _ f1 f2 _ < file
field="$f1 $f2"
```

Comment: It actually not solve my problem. Let say the second field is dynamic and it contains multiple delimiters the above solution will not help. We actually need to ignore last 7 delimiters and grep the value till the first delimiter and suppress the |

Comment: Ten please change you question to state this. As it stands it states that there is a single pipe in the sought after field (use plural where necessary)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, with `python`

```
<file python3 -c '
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    first, _, rest = line.strip().partition("|")
    rest_fields = rest.rsplit("|", 8)
    print(first, rest_fields[0].replace("|", ""), *rest_fields[1:], sep="|")
'
```